# Comparando dois valores para efectuar um if

Tags: javascript

Bom dia,boa tarde e boa noite.

Tenho um código que contempla uma listagem de checkbox e radio para que meu usuário selecione a operação desejada, porém ao marcar um radio o mesmo não deveria poder selecionar qualquer check que não fosse o da linha do rádio, mas não estou conseguindo fazer esse bloqueio para as demais linhas, ele funciona apenas na primeira linha da minha tabela e não tenho muito conhecimento em JS. A função que não funciona como imaginava é a validaMawb.

```
   function testaCheck(idMaster) {
    var inputs, i, checados = 0;
    inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if (inputs[i].type == "checkbox") {
            if (inputs[i].checked == true) {
                checados++;
                document.getElementsByName('DS_MD' + idMaster).value = idMaster;
                $("#formSelectMAWB").find("#masterDireto").val(idMaster);
            }

        }

    }

    if (checados > 1) {
                uncheckAll(inputs);
                document.getElementsByName('DS_MD' + idMaster).value = null;
                $("#formSelectMAWB").find("#masterDireto").val(null);
            }
};  

function uncheckAll(inputItems){
    alert("MAWB não selecionado ou MAWB diferente do Direto. Favor refazer a seleção");
    for (i = 0; i < inputItems.length; i++) {
        inputItems[i].checked = false;
    }
}

function validaMawb(){

var d = document.getElementsByName('DS_MD' + idMaster).value();
var m = document.getElementById('idMAWB').value;

if(d.value !== m.value){
    uncheckAll(inputs);
    document.getElementsByName('DS_MD' + idMaster).value = null;
    $("#formSelectMAWB").find("#masterDireto").val(null);   

}}

            <div class="linhaLista">
            <div class="campoLista TamanhoCampoLista7" title="">
                <div class="input-control span1 floatForm-left"> 
                    <label class="input-control radio">
                        <input type="radio" name="idMAWB" id="idMAWB" value="<%=ID_CD_MAWB%>" onClick="selecionaMAWB(this.value);">
                        <span class="helper"><%=DS_MAWB%></span>
                    </label>    

                    <label for="DS_MD<%=ID_CD_MAWB%>">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="DS_MD<%=ID_CD_MAWB%>" id="masterDireto<%=ID_CD_MAWB%>" onClick="testaCheck(<%=ID_CD_MAWB%>);validaMawb();">
                     <span class="helper"> Master Direto </span>
                     </label>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Não pode repetir id's, senão irá pegar sempre o primeiro.

Comment: Então aonde eu tenho o script do validaMawb eu teria de usar outro meio para chamar as variáveis de comparação?

Comment: Qual é a div que se repete?

Comment: A `<div class="input-control span1 floatForm-left">` que é a terceira div sempre se repete por ser parte da construção da listagem.

Comment: Teria que usar outro meio. Mas o seu código está todo errado. Tem que refazer ele quase todo, ao meu ver.

Comment: Entendi Sam, se puder me dar um rumo por onde começar ou algum lugar para estudar melhor agradeço, estou iniciando em js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de refazer o código, consegui o que necessitava com este tópico, caso alguém necessite segue abaixo o código funcional.

```
function testaCheck(idMaster) {
    var inputs, i, checados = 0;
    var idmasterOption = $("#formSelectMAWB").find("#idMAWB").val();
    inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if (inputs[i].type == "checkbox") {
            if (inputs[i].checked == true) {
                if (idMaster != idmasterOption) {
                     uncheckAll(inputs);                    
                    $("#formSelectMAWB").find("#masterDireto").val(null);
                    $("#formSelectMAWB").find("#idMAWB").val(null);
                        if ( valor != null){
                            $("#formSelectMAWB").find("#idMAWB").val(null);
                        }
                    }
                else {
                    document.getElementsByName('DS_MD' + idMaster).value = idMaster;
                    $("#formSelectMAWB").find("#masterDireto").val(idMaster);
                    }
                    checados++;
            }           
        }
    }   
    if (checados > 1) {
                uncheckAll(inputs);
                $("#formSelectMAWB").find("#masterDireto").val(null);
                $("#formSelectMAWB").find("#idMAWB").val(null);             
            }
};  

function uncheckAll(inputItems){
    alert("MAWB não selecionado ou MAWB diferente do Direto. Favor refazer a seleção");
    for (i = 0; i < inputItems.length; i++) {
        inputItems[i].checked = false;
    }
}
```